# Using LIKE for SQL Server with Python and list of values

Tags: python, sql, sql-server

I have a df with clients and products, and I have to get all information about this items from SQL Server,
but I have to parsed with substring, because DateBase contains product path, like this:

```
productpath:

fruits/apple
vegetables/tomato
```

And list of my products looks like this, but real list contains more than 1000 values:

```
df['prod']= ['apple', 'orange', 'tomato']
```

So I decided to use this code:

```
sql_sales = """
SELECT
    date,
    client,
    productpath,
    cost
FROM all_sales
WHERE 
    client == %(c1)s
    AND productpath LIKE '%%(prod)s%'

"""
```

And I've got mistake with using LIKE with this part **'%%(prod)s%'** like this:

> not enough arguments for format string unable to rollback

Without LIKE-part it is working

Comment: Side note `client ==` isn't valid syntax. T-SQL uses `=` for both assignment and comparison.

Comment: Does `productpath` have several '\' in it?

Comment: Yes, it has a different quantity of '/'

Answer (score 1):

One method uses a subquery:

```
. . . 
where . . . and
      exists (select 1
              from string_split('apple,orange,tomato', ',') s
              where all_sales.productpath like concat('%', s.value, '%')
             )
```

Comment: `split_part` still isn't a SQL Server function, Gordon. If you're thinking of `STRING_SPLIT` then you need to provide 2 parameters, the string to split and the delimiter.

Comment: Unfortunatelly my list with products contains more than 1000 items, that is why I can't put list in brackets

Comment: @Larnu . . . Arrgh.  To much Postgres thinking.  I fixed the answer.  Ironically, I would need multiple arguments for that original function in Postgres as well.

Comment: No worries, Gordon.  :)